# Get NTLM Credentials Fiddler

Tags: c#, web-services, fiddler

I am not sure if this is possible, but I am running into an issue where a Web Service call is giving me back a 401 Unauthorized. I have looked at the Fiddler logs and confirmed this, but I am passing in the correct credentials through my app. Is there anyway to get credentials that are being passed to the service by looking at the Fiddler Headers or Auth tabs?

Comment: is the web service container (IIS I suppose) configured to use Integrated?

Comment: Have you checked in the RAW section of Fiddler to see all you're passing as part of the request?

Comment: I have looked in the RAW and it looks like below
Authorization: Negotiate whole bunch of characters

Is there a tool to get the actual credentials from that encoded string?

Answer (score 1):

If you click the AUTH tab in Fiddler, it will show you the information about the authentication challenge response.

Note, however, that NTLM and Negotiate don't send the raw password over the network.

Is the target site HTTPS? If so, is Extended Protection enabled?

Comment: I took a look at the Auth tab and notice the domain and user is blank. What could be a possible cause of this?

Comment: Can you share a SAZ file?

Comment: here is a sample SAZ file. The first session is one that has empty credentials. The second session has populated credentials. The third has populated credentials, but I am supplying the credentials explicitly in the application.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2oacf1jtlrsxri7/Sample.saz

Comment: Was the "first session" here really the first session, or was it preceded by one or more 401 responses to anonymous requests?

Comment: Correct, there are 2 401s before the "1st" Session. Here is a SAZ file with just those 3 sessions.https://www.dropbox.com/s/9q2ptsbc7o61gbe/3%20Sessions.saz